# Insert added/changed/deleted rows to a 'Changelog' table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I've a task (SSIS Package) running every day that imports an Excel file (containing += 150k rows) into a SQL table. It does not append, but the option "Delete rows in destination table" is checked.

This Excel file contains rows that are changed/deleted/added.
I am looking for the best way to store the differences between the new Excel file and the older Excel file.

Not all rows are changed but maybe 2000/150k are changed and a few hundred are added and/or deleted.

What I have tried:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_Changelog]
ON [dbo].[Sheet1$]
FOR UPDATE
AS
WITH t1 AS 
(SELECT * FROM DELETED
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM INSERTED
INTERSECT
SELECT * FROM DELETED)

INSERT INTO dbo.changelog
SELECT *, getdate() as ChangedAt, 'OLD' as [Status] FROM t1;

WITH t2 AS 
(SELECT * FROM INSERTED
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM INSERTED
INTERSECT
SELECT * FROM DELETED)

INSERT INTO dbo.changelog
SELECT *, getdate() as ChangedAt, 'NEW' as [Status] FROM t2
```

However, I think this is not working because of 2 reasons:

1. Trigger is not fired after running an import task.
2. The rows are first deleted and then new data is inserted.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: If you are using SQL Server 2016 (13.x) and later [Temporal tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: *"Trigger is not fired after running an import task."* Then the task is disabling the trigger(s); you should be reviewing that.

Comment: *"The table if first deleted and then new data is inserted."* *Why* would you `DROP` the table and then recreate it? If you want a "blank slate" why not `TRUNCATE` it?

Comment: @Larnu yes, I mean the rows are deleted during the SSIS import, not the entire table.

Comment: Deleting all the data and reinserting *everything* (with the changes) isn't the same as updating/deleting/inserted the relevant rows; such a process makes it *very* difficult to monitor changes with or without a `TRIGGER`s. If you need to monitor the changes, you should be looking at doing some kind of upsert process, and (ideally) implement temporal tables, as @AnelHodžić suggested. Then everything is handled "automagically".

Comment: To do this effectively - using temporal tables or not - you need to change the import process in SSIS.  That process needs to be changed to load the data to a staging table in SQL Server - and then you can perform the comparison from the staging table to the final table to determine what needs to be inserted, updated or deleted.